# If This Then That random timer delay before action

Tags: if-this-then-that

Is there an option to have IFTTT perform the following action sequence:

- IF Facebook page status update
- THEN wait random 0-120 minutes
- Then post update to Twitter (or other target)

If so - how should I go about to make such recipe?

Answer (score 1):

Not with IFTTT but it is possible with a competitor - [Stringify](https://www.stringify.com/).

Stringify works in a similar manner to IFTTT, and will interact with it so that you can combine their abilities.

Stringify includes a [timer "thing"](https://search.stringify.com/things/qpfTVCl0_1) that can be inserted into a "flow" (equivalent to an IFTTT "recipe").  By default the timer will be fixed, but you can add a [mathematical function "thing"](https://search.stringify.com/things/eWZF53zT5ZufsFKpQFAFl9ZI8NLukR5A_1) to provide the timer duration.

Your "flow" can link to Facebook and Twitter as you require.

Comment: Link downl.........